# How search on an array of objects a specific field, using Ionic/AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a question in Ionic/AngularJs:

I have two searches on an object that are not working properly. 
The first `if (cartObj.cart.find (id)! = - 1)` { ---> This is okay.

The second is an if (cartObj.cart.findvovo (supply_id)! = - 1) { 
were if the value of the first if is equal to the field I want to fetch it accepts.

I want to fetch data only from "cart_item_supply": supply_id. How can I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVdZT.png)

In the screen attached I show my console with the array objects for you understand better.

This is my code:

```
var cartObj = {};
cartObj.cart=[];
cartObj.total_amount=0;
cartObj.total_qty=0;


// VERIFICA DE JÁ EXISTE ITENS NO CARRINHO
cartObj.cart.add=function(id,image,name,price,qty,supply_id,deliver){
    if( cartObj.cart.find(id)!=-1  ){
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'This product has already been added',
            template: 'Add more quantity to cart'

        });

    }if( cartObj.cart.findvovo(supply_id) !=-1){
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'This offer is from Another Grandmother',
            template: 'You can only buy offers from a single Grandma. Choose other offers from this same Grandma.'
        });
    }

    // IF DON´T EXIST, ADD
    else{
        cartObj.cart.push( { "cart_item_id": id , "cart_item_image": image , "cart_item_name": name , "cart_item_price": price , "cart_item_qty": qty, "cart_item_supply": supply_id, "cart_item_deliver": deliver  } );
        cartObj.total_qty+=1;   
        cartObj.total_amount+=parseInt(price);  
        console.log(cartObj);
    }
};

// SEACH PRODUCTS BY ID
cartObj.cart.find=function(id){ 
    console.log("chamou find");
    var result=-1;
    for( var i = 0, len = cartObj.cart.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        if( cartObj.cart[i].cart_item_id === id ) {
            result = i;
            console.log(result);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;        
};

// SEARCH CART_ITEM_SUPPLY === SUPPLY_ID --- HERE DONT FOUND
cartObj.cart.findvovo=function(supply_id){         
    var result=-1;
    for( var i = 0, len = cartObj.cart.length; i < len; i++ ) {            
        if( cartObj.cart[i].cart_item_supply === supply_id ) {            
            result = i;
            console.log(result);
            break;
        }
    };
    return result; 
};
```

Can you do resolve this question?

The especific code is here:

```
// SEARCH CART_ITEM_SUPPLY === SUPPLY_ID --- HERE DONT FOUND
cartObj.cart.findvovo=function(supply_id){         
    var result=-1;
    for( var i = 0, len = cartObj.cart.length; i < len; i++ ) {            
        if( cartObj.cart[i].cart_item_supply === supply_id ) {            
            result = i;
            console.log(result);
            break;
        }
    };
    return result; 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `_.every` from lodash

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#every

---

@Edit (based on comments)
`_.some(yourArray,{cart_item_supply: yourValue})`

this will return you `TRUE` if in Array will be `yourValue` more about this you will find there: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some

Comment: Hi @DiPix I'm using now lodash. It's work. But I can't get the first id and get only this first id from others registers.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Collection, your lodash query, and expected result?

Comment: The beginning of the creation of the objects there are nothing. The user choose a product and create the first object arrays. So, he choice another product. If this new product has the same value of the "cart_item_supply" field of array, then acept and create a new object, otherwise show a  message and don´t create a new object.

Comment: I think that I understand you. Please try this `_.some(yourArray,{cart_item_supply: yourValue})` - this will return you `TRUE` if in Array will be `yourValue` more about this you will find there: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#some - I hope it will help

Comment: @Ramos Mark as answered :)